# Como verificar se o arquivo é uma imagem do Input type="file"

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um input type="file" que iria servir para o usuário adicionar uma foto de perfil e gostaria de verificar se o arquivo é uma imagem antes.

Já fiz a verificação via PHP, mas gostaria de fazer via Javascript também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, inclusive, você pode adicionar no HTML também caso não saiba:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>
```

Vou te dar a base, depois é só implementar condições:

```js
function validation(){
  var file = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var file = file.files[0];
  
  document.getElementById("logger").innerHTML = "Nome: " + file.name + " <br />Type: " + file.type + "<br />Tamanho: " + file.size;
}
```

```html
 <input type="file" id="myFile" accept="image/*" onchange="validation()" />

  <br />
  
  <div id="logger">
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, não sabia mesmo, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o atributo `type` do arquivo, ele vai retornar o tipo no formato `image/png`, é só verificar se contém o texto `image`

Ex.:

```js
var file = document.getElementById('file');

function test() {
    if (file.files[0].type.includes('image')) {
        alert('É uma imagem')
    } else {
         alert('Outro tipo de arquivo')
    }
}

document.getElementById('testButton').addEventListener('click', test)
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button id="testButton">Testar</button>
```

Obs.: O tipo é detectado a partir da extensão do arquivo, o que não pode ser muito seguro

---

Fiz um outro exemplo baseado nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672957/5325043), é mais complexo, porém mais seguro do que o anterior:

```js
var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput')
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
    var header = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       header += arr[i].toString(16);
   }
    var type = ""

    switch (header) {
        case "89504e47":
            type = "image/png";
            break;
        case "47494638":
            type = "image/gif";
            break;
        case "ffd8ffe0":
        case "ffd8ffe1":
        case "ffd8ffe2":
        case "ffd8ffe3":
        case "ffd8ffe8":
            type = "image/jpeg";
            break;
        default:
            type = "unknown"; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
    }
    
    alert(type)
};

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var blob = fileInput.files[0]
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar pela extensão do arquivo usando `.match` com o regex:

```
/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
function isImagem(i){
   
   var img = i.value.split(".");
   var ext = "."+img.pop();

   if(!ext.match(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i)){
      alert("Não é imagem");
      i.value = '';
      return;
   }

   alert("OK!");
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="isImagem(this)" />
```